# Obtain AES CBC key when I have IV, plain text and cyphered text

Tags: encryption, cryptography, aes

I am looking for a way of obtaining the key from this set of information, I know for a fact that we are using 16 byte blocks with CBC and I have the first 16 byte plaintext and cyphered, along with the used IV.

At the moment I can test if a key is correct by comparing the output, but I cannot bruteforce 16 character keys for obvious reasons, reading other posts it was my understanding that having the data I have it might be possible to get the key.

Any hint?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are trying to do is called a "known plaintext atack", you have both the cyphertext and the plaintext, all that you lack is the key used.  Unfortunately, all modern cyphers are designed to resist such attacks.  Unless you have extremely sophisticated mathematical skills, you will not be able to find the key this way.  AES is resistant to a known plaintext attack.

You will have to try some other method of determining the key.  Has the key owner left it written on a piece of paper somewhere?

Comment: Not even having the Initialization Vector? I am aware that AES is plaintext attack resistant, but I was hoping that having the IV would give me some advantage there.

Comment: @ArkaitzJimenez No that won't help you at all.

Comment: @ArkaitzJimenez the IV simply gets XOR'ed with the first block of plain text to make sure that the identical data in the plain text won't create an identical cipher text. Otherwise you could e.g. easily see the encryption of two times "yes". It's not part of the AES block encrypt and is in no way linked with the key (or, at least, it shouldn't be).

Comment: @rossum, I wouldn't say its "unfortunate" that AES is resistant to known plaintext attack. It'd be pretty useless if it weren't. :D Following up on CodesInChaos's note, the IV is considered public information in block ciphers, so everyone knows the ciphertext and the IV.

Comment: @Rob Napier, Put it down to British understatement.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if AES has been applied as it should be then you cannot find the key. However, judging on the amount of incorrect implementations on stackoverflow, the key may as well be a password, or a simple SHA-256 of a string. If you can obtain information about how the key was generated/applied or stored you may be able to get around even AES-256.

Otherwise your only attack vector is breaking AES or brute forcing the key. In that case I wish you good luck, because brute forcing a 256 bit key is completely out of the question, even with a quantum computer. Unless vulnerabilities are found, of course, AES is *not* provably secure after all. There *may* be a vulnerability.

Comment: would you mind give more details about how you would recover the key knowning for instance that the key is a sha-256 of a string please ? i didn't thought it could be helpful

Comment: @rebrec You could brute force it if you know the *alphabet* of the password. Or you could perform a dictionary attack if you know the password consists of or contains words. Rainbow tables could also be considered. Of course there is no telling if this will be successful. If you're not lucky then you'll burn a lot of energy for nothing. I'm not a black hatter, but possibly you could use John the Ripper or similar tools.

Comment: In other words: you guess the input to the hash, calculate the key and perform decryption of a single block of ciphertext. If you get something that looks like plaintext you try another block or two. Stop if it looks like the message.

Comment: But what would make it more easier ? i mean knowing that it's AES-256 and that the key is a sha-256 will provide what ? appart from knowing that the key has an exact length of 256 bits ?